# Jackson JSON Representation Issue

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, jackson2

I've been using Jackson 2.8.9 with Spring Boot 1.5.7 for one of my projects and came across a simple issue that I haven't been able to resolve. I was hoping to get some clarification/suggestion on how to get this issue resolved.

My Base Interface

```
public interface IMessage {}
```

POJO Entity:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyEntity implements IMessage {

    @JsonProperty(value = "f1")
    private String fieldOne;

    @JsonProperty(value = "f2")
    private String fieldTwo;

    @JsonProperty(value = "f3")
    private String fieldThree;
}
```

I'm making use of `restTemplate.postForEntity(new URI(url), entity, MyEntity.class);` from the Spring to perform the request to external API, the expected output for the JSON data is as follows.

```
{
    "fieldOne": "value",
    "fieldTwo": "value",
    "fieldThree": "value",
}
```

However, the values I am getting when I return the response back is as follows.

```
{
    "f1": "value",
    "f2": "value",
    "f3": "value",
}
```

The POJO Object is created perfectly and I can use the `getters` and `setters` to perform the operation as expected. However, the JSON string representation is not what I expect it to be.

I am unable to identify the root cause of this issue. Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: what do you expect out if it `@JsonProperty(value = "f1")`?  Jackson does exactly what you defined for it.

Comment: Jacson user @JsonProperty(value = "name") as field name while deserialization. What are you except? Is it your own API?

Comment: @Maxim I am using an API created by someone else that sends a response with JSON Keys `f1`, `f2` etc. I want them to be mapped to `fieldOne`, `fieldTwo` etc  I tried to make use of a custom `PropertyNamingStrategy` and it didn't work. So, I tried the `@JsonProperty` and that didn't work either. What's the best way to do this?